# understanding the meaning of varying

Tags: java, variables, return-value

Write a method to calculate the monthly payments you would have to make over a given number of years to pay off a loan at a given interest rate compounded continuously. The method takes the number of years t, the principal P, and the annual interest rate r as arguments. The desired value is given by the formula (P ert/ 12 t). Use Math.exp(). The signature of the method should be: `public static double monthlyPayment(double years, double principal, double rate)` Use the method to write a program Payments that generates a set of the monthly payments one would have to make for a $20,000 loan over 5 years at interest rates varying from 5% to 8% in 0.25% increments.

```
public class Payments {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(double r=0.05; r<=0.08; r+=0.0025) {
            System.out.println(monthlyPayment(5,20000,r));
        }

    }
    public static double monthlyPayment(double years,double principal,double rate) {
        return ((principal*(Math.exp(years*rate)))/(12*years));
    }

}
```

This is what I wrote so far and I'm not sure what to do actually, I don't understand by what the mean by varying from 5% to 8% in 0.25% increment ! Can anybody explain please ?

Comment: No we wont help you with your homework.

Comment: I guess this is an assignment. Can you mark the text of the assignment as such?

Comment: Provide results for 5%, 5.25%, 5.5% and so on until 8%.

Comment: I think they want you to `loop` through interest rates from 5% to 8% with 0.25% increment.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi I'm not telling you to write me the code just explain what varying from 5% to 8% in 0.25% increment means !

Comment: You already got several explanations.

Comment: Yup and that's why I'm lost .. I thought I have to loop through rate

Comment: Might be the only time I can say this but I think this belongs on: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I edited my code ... can anybody check it now ?

Comment: Do not remove your question's content in this manner. It is not fair to those who may have answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

The question is telling you to create a table for

```
5.00%
5.25%
...
...
7.75%
8.00
```

Comment: Can you check what I did ?

Comment: I got these : 428.0084722292471    433.3921560561637   438.8435582892072   444.363530721067   449.9529358586677  455.6126470579322   461.34354866025046  467.1465361306578 473.02251619775245 478.9724069953748 484.9971382060672
491.0976512063385

Comment: Ok now you just need to format it `System.out.println(r + "\t" + monthlyPayment(5, 2000, r) + "\n");`. This will give you a cleaner looking table.  That should do it for you, unless something's wrong with your math.  I won't help you with that.